# How to get the text value from the input in p:autocomplete if selection was not made

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces, autocomplete

I want to use the p:autocomplete element for searching persons in my application. If the the user selects an item from the autocomplete list then some action is called. But when he doesn't select any, there is button where he can search by the entered String and a table of persons will be shown.

So far I have an itemSelect event listener, which handles the first part but I identify the persons by Long IDs so the value of the p:autocomplete field is bound to a managedBean Long property. When I don't make any selection a hit the button to search I don't have the string value.

Is it possible to somehow get the String value from the inputField in the backing bean? The one option that I am thinking of is to have a hidden element next to the autocomplete and set the value of the hidden element with the value of the autocomplete when clicking the search button. However, I have all this in a custom component so I don't really know what are the IDs of the components and therefore cannot write the Javascript function (without some dirty unsafe hacking).

Comment: `I identify the persons by Long IDs so the value of the p:autocomplete field is bound to a managedBean Long property.` It sounds quite extrange to me to do something like that. Does it make sense to autocomplete an id field? Anyway, please post some of your code to make this question easier to understand.

Comment: On what event do you now want to get the value into the autocomplete? If no action was performed on the autocomplete, no event will be triggered.

Comment: @ExtremeBiker: I do autocomplete on the name of the person, but the selected value is Long (that is just to clarify that I don't need any converter)

Comment: @Kolossus: On button click. It should be simple - do autocomplete, if user selects someone do some action, if not keep the text in the field and after clicking the search button search by the text value from the input field.

Comment: Show some code; your explanation is not particularly clear

Comment: @Filip Majernik i am facing the same issue, did you found a solution.

Comment: Only a dirty hack. The value is sent in the request, i.e. if your component id is search-text then there is a request parameter search-text-auto_input. So I extract it like this:
String paramValue = new String();
        FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Map<String, String> parameterMap = ctx.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
        for(String key : parameterMap.keySet()) {
            if(key.endsWith(AUTOCOMPLETE_QUERY_REQUEST_PARAM_SUFFIX)) {
                paramValue = parameterMap.get(key);
            }
        }

        return paramValue;